# Disable this Control - SP2013/IP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I have an InfoPath 2013 web browser compatabile form with two views - read only and default. The default view has several fields that must be filled in. I have 3 different group of users that will fill in the form. How can I disable the fields based on current user permission based on group without using SOAP services?

I've researched this and all I could find were examples for 2007 and 2010 which doesn't seem to work with 2013.

I have an InfoPath 2013 form with two views, default view and read only. Within the form there are sections where a user can enter data.

- There are three user groups (Submitter, Owner, Liaison) that will enter data and "everyone" can view but not enter data.
- These all currently exist as SP2013 site groups.

(a) I was told on other sites that I would have to create a SP list and recreate the groups and users in the list. 
(b) Another site said I would only have to recreate the groups and permissions in the SP list.

The SOAP service is not fully implemented in our site.

So is either a or b correct?

Finally, how would the rule look in IP2013 to disable the control based on the SP list?

Thanks.